# Is there a word for the total amount of time you weren't working in a day?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, antonyms, negation

I can say that I plan to work 7 hours today, but how do I say I plan to "not work" for 2 hours?

"Be on a break/pause for 2 hours" or "Rest for 2 hours" doesn't work because I might take several smaller breaks.

"Not work for 2 hours" sounds too vague because I am referring to periods of rest during the workday.

Maybe, "I plan to take breaks that add up to 2 hours".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pluralise *break,* or be a bit more specific:

- Take two hours of breaks
- Be on breaks for two hours
- I shall take various breaks for two hours (or *totalling two hours*)

Or

- I shall do seven hours’ work between 0900 and 1800 hours.

Comment: "Two hours of breaks" or "Breaks totaling two hours" is pretty standard job lingo in the US. Well, *two* hours is unusual, but you get the idea.

Comment: Voted by mistake and could not undo. So sorry.

Answer (score 3):

*Downtime* is used at lot of workplaces to denote the time when a worker is expected to work but is instead not working due to his choice or otherwise (system down or other unforeseen circumstances).

Comment: That was my first thought: downtime. When I'm not working, I'm down (unhappy). That's what happens when you're a workaholic.

Answer (score 2):

WordNet 3.0 cited in the Free Dictionary:

> Noun 1. **[time off](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/time+off)** - a time period when you are not required to work; "he requested time off to attend his grandmother's funeral"

You would say:
**"I plan to take two hours' time off."**

Wikipedia notes time off and [Paid time off](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paid_time_off) (PTO) in AmE:

> In the USA, Paid time off (PTO) is a feature in some employee agreements that provides a "resource" of hours that an employee can draw from to take time off from work, without having to specify a reason.

Note that the phrase is also used in a broader sense or in various contextual meanings, such as *time when you are not at work or at school* (Macmillan), *a period when one is absent from work for a holiday, through sickness, etc* (Collins), *A break from one's employment or school, as in I need some time off from teaching to work on my dissertation* , or *He took time off to make some phone calls* (dictionary.reference.com), and such other.

Answer (score 1):

**Take two hours of rest** will cover a single extended period or multiple short breaks that total 120 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

"I plan to spend two hours at leisure."

Definitions of "at leisure" from CollinsDictionary.com:

> at leisure in American English
>
> 1. having free or spare time
> 2. with no hurry
> 3. not occupied or engaged

Please note: "At leisure" might sound a little old-fashioned, or carry a whiff of the military. I investigated using Google and found no particular military association. "At ease" is similar and is most assuredly a military-associated term.